# Table rows not correctly working with pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using pagination for my table. I want to show 5 rows at a time. I have 10 items in my table. So that mean pagination should show 1 and 2. It does show 1 and 2. My problem is when it 1 in pagination, table shows  first 5 record (1 to 5), If I click 2 in pagination table should show 6 to 10 record set. But in my situation it shows 3 to 7 record.

Controller...

```
function index(){

    $data['villages'] = $this->m->getVote();
    $this->load->view('index',$data);

}

function index1(){
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url']=base_url().'homecon/index1';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['per_page'] = 5;

    $page = $this->uri->segment(3,0);

    $data['villages'] = $this->m->getVote($config['per_page'],$page);
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->m->getTotalRow();
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('index1',$data);

}
```

Model...

```
private $lastQuery ='';

public function getVote($limit,$start){
    $this->db->order_by('voter_id','ASC');
    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    $query=$this->db->get('voter_details');
    $this->lastQuery = $this->db->last_query();
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }


}
public function getTotalRow(){
        $sql =explode('LIMIT', $this->lastQuery);
        $query = $this->db->query($sql[0]);
        $result = $query->result();
        return count($result);
    }
```

[Pagination 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EBQ8.jpg)

[Pagination 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbSeo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the page to the model, and not the start index.

Try this

```
$data['villages'] = $this->m->getVote($config['per_page'], $page*$config['per_page']);
```